# How to retrieve a FileBlob from 'ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile' instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I have used 'remotipart' gem to upload files asynchronously to server side. The instance passed to the server side is of 'UploadedFile' .

The Rails API mentions all the methods( like read(), open() ) and attributes for the class, however I am not sure how to retrieve the File and store it on the database?

Googling took me to no tutorials using this class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is rarely documented because most people use gems to handle file uploads.

Let's say your object is called `file`. You could determine the path using this:

```
file.tempfile.to_path.to_s
```

You should move the file because it's stored in `/tmp` and might be deleted by the system. You can use `FileUtils.mv` method for this. Then you can add the new path of the file to the database.