# Receiving emails with attachments from SendGrid in Rails 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email-attachments, sendgrid

I can successfully receive email from SendGrid and process its data. 
My problem is the emails attachments.

When I look at what is posted for each attachment I get something in the lines of:

```
"attachment12"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000008a793f8 
                  @original_filename="image036.png", 
                  @content_type="image/png", 
                  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
                            name=\"attachment12\";
                            filename=\"image036.png\"\r\n
                            Content-Type: image/png\r\n", 
                  @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120620-35076-1xav4k1>
                >
```

Rather than the

```
Array
(
  [attachment1] => Array
    (
      [name] => Upload.csv
      [type] => text/csv
      [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpo34iHI
      [error] => 0
      [size] => 76
    )
)
```

Which is quoted in the Parse API shown [enter link description here](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/parse-api-2/)
Obviously, Rails is being elegant as always.

However, my questions are:

1. Where are the files, where they downloaded as implied? I cannot find them (I would be worried if this happened)

---

I am actually reading into ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, according to the docs I should be able to do params['attachment12'].read

I will post my findings

---

1. Production is Heroku so I would need to either stick the files in some sort of container like the DB, Mongo or S3
2. I am guessing the file is actually at sendgrid but their support does not understand my question and revert me back to the parse api! There is probably a URL but I cannot get to the bottom of it with their support. Unfortunately.

Comment: I'm one of the developer evangelists at SendGrid. Sorry that support didn't have an acceptable answer to your question.  I posted a response below that will hopefully clear things up. Also, feel free to reach out to community (at) sendgrid (dot) com if you have any more issues.

Comment: thanks swift... I was on the right track and managed to read the attachments as above last night. Thanks I for the heads up on the community. Sendgrid JustWorks TM - nice service.

Comment: Both answers below are correct.... I just use params['attachment12'].read to get the actually read the file contents. Kudos to Bitterzoet and Swift for their help

Comment: Swift - how would you do it for a rails on on heroku using PandaStream?   Neither of these work for me when trying to upload a video file:         panda_video = Panda::Video.create!(:file => File.new(attachment1.tempfile.to_path.to_s))
        panda_video = Panda::Video.create!(:file => attachment1.tempfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are actually POSTed to your server but you get an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` to work with. If you take a look at the [class description](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile) you can see you have a couple of things available to you:

The `original_filename` attribute obviously, but you can use `.read` to actually read out the contents and save it or you can probably pass the tempfile directly to whatever gem you are using.

If you can tell me what kind of upload solution you use (paperclip, carrierwave) if any, I can help you a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the file was actually uploaded to your server already and is being stored in the `tempfile` attribute of the `UploadFile`.  You can use the following to access the full file path:

```
params['attachment12'].tempfile.to_path.to_s
```

*Source: [How to retrieve a FileBlob from 'ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile' instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544768/how-to-retrieve-a-fileblob-from-actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile-instance)*

---

And just to make it clear, the files aren't actually on SendGrid's servers at this point in the process.  They have already been posted to you and are stored somewhere on your server (probably in the `/tmp` directory).