# rails read xls uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xls

I have uploaded .xls file but I can't read it by roo.
In controller I have:

```
  def create
    name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
    directory = "public/uploads"
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    file =  File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:file].read) }
    flash[:notice] = "File uploaded"
    file.inspect
    Product.import(params[:upload][:file].original_filename)    
    redirect_to upload_path
  end
```

In model:

```
  def self.import(file)

  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
 end


  def self.open_spreadsheet(upload)
    directory = "public/uploads"
    file = File.join(directory, upload)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

But upload variable I have String and I can't use file methods. How I can open already uploaded file for reading by roo gem?

Answer (score 1):

I described how to work with uploads without using gems here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545030/1001324

You cant work with the original filename on the serveside like you do it.